# If $H \leq G, \exists g \in G$ such that $HgHg^{-1} = G$, then $H = G$

Tags: group-theory

Just wanted some overall feedback from a homework question.

Let $G$ be a group where $H \leq G$. Prove that if $\exists g \in G$ such that $HgHg^{-1} = G$, then $H = G$.

$\it{Proof.}$ Note that $H = G \iff H \subseteq G$ and $G \subseteq H$. Obviously, since $H \leq G$, then by definition, it follows that $H \subseteq G$. Now we show that $G \subseteq H$.
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
 HgHg^{-1} = G
 & \iff HgHg^{-1}g = Gg\\
 & \iff HgH = Gg\\
 & \iff HgH = G \text{ since }Gg = G, \forall g \in G\\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
I'm a little stuck in seeing how $HgH = G \Rightarrow G \subseteq H$, if it does. Any clarification would help.

Kindest regards.

Comment: Ah I see, the notation $H\leq G$ only means that $H$ is a subgroup, right? Not necessarily normal.

Comment: The question does not specify that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Ok, I will delete the comment. Thx for clarifying!

Comment: Yes, I guess. As that would make the claim trivial.

Comment: $HgH = G \Rightarrow 1 \in HgH \Rightarrow g \in H \Rightarrow HgH=H$.

Comment: Could you explain your logic?

Comment: What is there to explain?

Comment: Perhaps I am not seeing it immediately,but how exactly does $1 \in HgH \Rightarrow g \in H?$ I'm assuming that $1$ is what you are using to denote the identity element. Thank you Derek.

Comment: Yes, $1$ denotes the identity element. So what does $1 \in HgH$ mean?

Comment: @DerekHolt: You should post it as an answer. +1

Answer (score 4):

To repeat my comment, $HgH=G \Rightarrow 1 \in HgH \Rightarrow \exists h_1,h_2 \in H {\rm\ s.t.\ }1=h_1gh_2 \Rightarrow g = h_1^{-1}h_2^{-1} \in H \Rightarrow$ $HgH=H \Rightarrow H=G$.

Comment: $g = h_1^{-1}h_2^{-1}$, surely?

Comment: Just testing :)